# Recording a value to a cell at a specific time

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract a number from a cell(H5) at an exact time. My sheet is connected to a website and the sheet (and cell H5) is updated every second.I have a countdown timer in cell(D2), when this timer equals 2 minutes before the start of the event, then i want to extract the value in cell(H5) and put it in a new cell(AA1) and i want the value to remain there, as the value in cell(H5) will change again after a few seconds.

**Addendum from OP's comment:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address <> "$D$2" Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Range("AA1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  Range("AA1").Value = Range("H5").Value 
  Application.EnableEvents = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Your countdown timer should probably be reworked or an `Application.OnTime` command added. Possibly a globally public variable added too. It's a shame you decided it wasn't important enough to share your existing countdown code so we could see what is actually going on.

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. that sounds a bit advanaced for me!! if i send you the excel sheet and an explanation, would you be able to helpme with it?

Comment: Hi Jeeped,[Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address <> "$D$2" Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("AA1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("AA1").Value = Range("H5").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub/]

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still completely oblivious as to how this new code sample addition has anything to do with your request. You stated that you have a countdown timer and wish to have something occur 2 minutes before *'the start of the event'*. So where's the countdown timer?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, any silly countdown timer should be as unobtrusive as possible. The code you provided is a worksheet's `Worksheet_Change` event macro that attempts to deal with a value change in the cell containing the timer countdown display. Anything dealing with the countdown reaching the two minute mark should be within the countdown procedure; adding another process to the works can only a) consume more resources and b) add more potential for conflicts. Here is how I would go about it.

First off, I like to have immediate control over any timer routine. Typically, I choose a cell on the worksheet that I can double-click to turn the timer on and off. In this example, I will pick A1 and use a custom number format of `[Color10]\RU\N\NI\N\G;[Color13]\EV\E\NT!;[Color9]w\aiti\n\g;` for the cell.

In the worksheet's code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab ► View Code) paste the following.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then
        Cancel = True
        On Error GoTo SafeExit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value2 = Abs(Int(Not CBool(Target.Value2)))
        bINTIMER = CBool(Target.Value2)
        If bINTIMER Then
            Me.Range("D2") = TimeSerial(0, 2, 10)
            Application.OnTime earliesttime:=Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), _
              procedure:="Countdown", latesttime:=Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2), schedule:=True
            bRANH5XFER = False
        Else
            Me.Range("D2") = TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "D2" Then
        Debug.Print Format(Target.Value, "[hh]:mm:ss")
    End If
End Sub
```

The `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` turns the timer on and off by double-clicking A1. The custom number format advises of the current status. A publicly declared variable (bINTIMER, defined in the next step) is used to determine whether the timer is active or not for other operations.

The `Worksheet_Change` event sub is there solely to prove that it is not involved in the timer process unless the value in D2 is manually changed. It has no purpose in this example and can be removed or modified for other purposes.

In a module sheet (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd> in the VBE) paste the following.

```
Option Explicit

Public bINTIMER As Boolean
Public bRANH5XFER As Boolean

Public Sub CountDown()
    If bINTIMER Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            If .Range("D2").Value < TimeSerial(0, 0, 2) Then
                .Range("A1") = -1
                .Range("D2") = 0
                MsgBox "Countdown is zero." & Chr(10) & "Run your event."
                .Range("A1") = 0
            Else
                .Range("D2") = .Range("D2").Value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
                Application.OnTime earliesttime:=Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), _
                  procedure:="Countdown", latesttime:=Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2), schedule:=True
                If Not bRANH5XFER And .Range("D2").Value < TimeSerial(0, 2, 0) Then
                    .Range("H5").Copy
                    .Range("AA1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    bRANH5XFER = Not bRANH5XFER
                ElseIf Not CBool(Second(.Range("D2").Value) Mod 3) Then
                    .Range("H5") = CLng(Rnd() * 99)
                End If
            End If
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the countdown routine. It handles both the two minute mark and the countdown reaching zero. I've added some code to put a random number into H5 every three seconds. Event handling is turned off within the countdown timer because I want the very least amount of outside influence to occur while I process the countdown. I've left a message box where the countdown reaches zero so you will know where to run your 'event'.

This is an example of what would happen when the countdown reaches zero.

[image: Countdown Timer]

I've made that sample binary macro-enabled workbook available on my public DropBox [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Application_OnTime_Timer_w_Secondary_Event.xlsb). I do not know at this time how it will stay there.

[Application_OnTime_Timer_w_Secondary_Event.xlsb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Application_OnTime_Timer_w_Secondary_Event.xlsb)

Comment: [Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
If Range("N60").Value = 1 Then
    Range("C62").Value = Range("H5").Value
Else   
End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub/]

Answer (score 0):

i sorted the answer myself, i was quiet simple in the end, no need for big lines of code. i had an if staement setup in N60 and then ran the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
If Range("N60").Value = 1 Then
Range("C62").Value = Range("H5").Value
Else   
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help anyway